# Remove Element from xDocument based on value in repeating segment

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In the XML below I am trying to remove the /Bundle/entry/resource/Patient/contained/Patient elements when any of the /Bundle/entry/resource/Patient/contained/Patient/identifier/system value attributes contain "remove-this-Patient" , I could use the full value == "https://example.com/remove-this-Patient" but the "contain" is better for me since the url section can be from multiple places and be slightly different.

I have tried the two code samples below and other variations but none work. The code runs without error but the target Patient element is not removed.

Just as a test I tried using the /Bundle/entry/resource/Patient/contained/Patient/id element in the "where" clause and I was able to get this to work, so I think it has something to do with the /Bundle/entry/resource/Patient/contained/Patient/identifier element being repeating inside the Patient element.

Starting XML

```
<Bundle>
    <id value="xxxx" />
    <entry>
    <fullUrl value="xxxxxxx" />
        <resource>
            <Patient>
                <id value="xxxx" />
                <contained>
                    <Practitioner>
                        <id value="xx"/>                        
                    </Practitioner>
                </contained>
                <contained>
                    <Patient>
                        <id value="xxxx" />                     
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                    
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="http://example.com/remove-this-Patient" />
                            <value value="xxx" />
                        </identifier>
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                    
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="https://example.com/some-other-value" />
                            <value value="xxx" />
                        </identifier>
                    </Patient>
                </contained>
                <contained>
                    <Patient>
                        <id value="xxxx" />                     
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                    
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="https://example.com/some-other-thing" />
                            <value value="xxx" />
                        </identifier>
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                    
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="https://example.com/some-other-value" />
                            <value value="xxx" />
                        </identifier>
                    </Patient>
                </contained>
            </Patient>
        </resource>     
    </entry>
</Bundle>
```

Desired output would have the /contained/Patient element removed when the child element identifier/system value = "http://example.com/remove-this-Patient"

```
<Bundle>
    <id value="xxxx" />
    <entry>
    <fullUrl value="xxxxxxx" />
        <resource>
            <Patient>
                <id value="xxxx" />
                <contained>
                    <Practitioner>
                        <id value="xx"/>                        
                    </Practitioner>
                </contained>
                <contained>
                    
                </contained>
                <contained>
                    <Patient>
                        <id value="xxxx" />                     
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                    
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="https://example.com/some-other-thing" />
                            <value value="xxx" />
                        </identifier>
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                    
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="https://example.com/some-other-value" />
                            <value value="xxx" />
                        </identifier>
                    </Patient>
                </contained>
            </Patient>
        </resource>     
    </entry>
</Bundle>
```

The two queries below are my attempt to make it work with XDocument, but neither work. They run without error but do not remove the Patient.

```
    xdoc.Root.Descendants("entry").Descendants("resource").Descendants("Patient").Descendants("contained").Descendants("Patient").Where(x => x.Element("identifier").Element("system").Attribute("value").Value.Contains("remove-this-Patient")).Remove();
    

    
 xdoc.Root.Descendants("entry").Descendants("resource").Descendants("Patient").Descendants("contained").Descendants("Patient").Where(x => (string)x.Descendants("identifier").Where(y=> ("system").Attribute("value")=="https://example.com/remove-this-Patient").Remove();
```

Comment: It is a perfect job for XSLT. Are you open to i t?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with XSLT but I'm open to learning

Comment: Please update your question, and add a desired output.

Comment: Class object in c# do not get removed if there is multiple links to the object.  The delete calls the default dispose method which checks the number of links on a object and only calls the garbage collection when there are no link to the object.  The remove is only deleting one link to the object.  So either there are more than one link to the object or the  path you are using isn't finding the descendant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on XSLT transformation.

The XSLT below is following a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

The 2nd template removes not needed **"/Bundle/entry/resource/Patient/contained/Patient"** XML elements based on the presence of the **'remove-this-Patient'** value in the **@value** attribute.

**Input XML**

```
<Bundle>
    <id value="xxxx"/>
    <entry>
        <fullUrl value="xxxxxxx"/>
        <resource>
            <Patient>
                <id value="xxxx"/>
                <contained>
                    <Practitioner>
                        <id value="xx"/>
                    </Practitioner>
                </contained>
                <contained>
                    <Patient>
                        <id value="xxxx"/>
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="http://example.com/remove-this-Patient"/>
                            <value value="xxx"/>
                        </identifier>
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="https://example.com/some-other-value"/>
                            <value value="xxx"/>
                        </identifier>
                    </Patient>
                </contained>
                <contained>
                    <Patient>
                        <id value="xxxx"/>
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="https://example.com/some-other-thing"/>
                            <value value="xxx"/>
                        </identifier>
                        <identifier>
                            <type>
                                <coding>
                                </coding>
                            </type>
                            <system value="https://example.com/some-other-value"/>
                            <value value="xxx"/>
                        </identifier>
                    </Patient>
                </contained>
            </Patient>
        </resource>
    </entry>
</Bundle>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Bundle/entry/resource/Patient/contained/Patient[identifier/system[contains(@value, 'remove-this-Patient')]]">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<Bundle>
  <id value="xxxx" />
  <entry>
    <fullUrl value="xxxxxxx" />
    <resource>
      <Patient>
        <id value="xxxx" />
        <contained>
          <Practitioner>
            <id value="xx" />
          </Practitioner>
        </contained>
        <contained />
        <contained>
          <Patient>
            <id value="xxxx" />
            <identifier>
              <type>
                <coding />
              </type>
              <system value="https://example.com/some-other-thing" />
              <value value="xxx" />
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
              <type>
                <coding />
              </type>
              <system value="https://example.com/some-other-value" />
              <value value="xxx" />
            </identifier>
          </Patient>
        </contained>
      </Patient>
    </resource>
  </entry>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for providing this. I am in the process of implementing your suggestion. I will mark it as the answer once I get it working.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @David, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. It is just one line template in XSLT!

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string id = "xxxx";

            List<XElement> possibleDeletes = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Element("identifier") != null) && (string)x.Element("id").Attribute("value") == id).ToList();

            foreach (XElement possibleDelete in possibleDeletes)
            {
                List<XElement> identifiers = possibleDelete.Elements("identifier").ToList();
                foreach (XElement identifier in identifiers)
                {
                    if (((string)identifier.Element("system").Attribute("value")).Contains("remove")) identifier.Remove(); 
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
 
}
```